# Change color of svg ( icon) via css in angular 8

Tags: angular, svg

I work with svg icons and try to change the color of the icon and its not work.

But when I change the icon explicit in the file it work (fill: 'red).

This is my svg file inside assets folder:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="23" height="23" viewBox="0 0 23 23">
    <path fill="#00A1DE" fill-rule="nonzero" stroke="#00A1DE" d="M21.708 10.77H12.23V1.293a.73.73 0 0 0-1.458 0v9.479H1.29a.73.73 0 0 0 0 1.458h9.48v9.48a.73.73 0 1 0 1.458 0v-9.48h9.48a.73.73 0 1 0 0-1.458z"/>
</svg>
```

icons.scss inside icons folder in style folder file:

```
.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

.plus {
  content: url('/assets/images/icons/plus.svg');
}
```

I use the icon in component.html like this:

```
 <i class="icon plus"></I>
```

and I try to edit the color in component.css:

```
.icon {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 2px;
  color: green
}
```

The position and bottom work but the color change only the box background I need to change the icon color not the background.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.filter` of css to change appearances of `svg`. You can not directly change svgs.

```
.icon{
  filter: invert(48%) sepia(79%) saturate(2476%) hue-rotate(86deg) brightness(118%) contrast(119%);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [CSS Variables](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables):

```
<svg id="plus" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M1 8H15" stroke="var(--icon-color, #fff)"/>
  <path d="M8 1L8 15" stroke="var(--icon-color, #fff)"/>
</svg>
```

CSS:

```
.icon {
    --icon-color: red;
}
```

Works with <mat-icon> and SVG icon sets

Answer (score 1):

A bit more on accepted answer
You can also use css filter property to change the color of svg icons which are imported by img src tag.

Moreover to change hex color to filter visit
[https://isotropic.co/tool/hex-color-to-css-filter/#:~:text=Simply%20paste%20your%20color%20(as,the%20CSS%20code%20as%20needed.](https://isotropic.co/tool/hex-color-to-css-filter/#:%7E:text=Simply%20paste%20your%20color%20(as,the%20CSS%20code%20as%20needed.)

for example

```css
  .icon{
filter: invert(36%) sepia(10%) saturate(1316%) hue-rotate(153deg)                      brightness(91%) contrast(86%);
}
```

```html
<img width="20px" class="icon" src="../../../assets/icons/sort.svg" alt="24-h">
```

[1]: https://isotropic.co/tool/hex-color-to-css-filter/#:~:text=Simply%20paste%20your%20color%20(as,the%20CSS%20code%20as%20needed.